# What is the use of having a @Configuration class define another @Configuration class?

Tags: java, spring

In the code I'm playing with I've seen a few places were an @Configuration class does nothing but define a static class. The format varies, but generally something like this:

```
@Configuration 
public class someAutoConfiguration {

   @EnableConfigurationProperty(...)
   @utoConfigureAfter(...)
   @Configureation
   public static class someConfiguration
   {
        @Autowired
         //whatever needs autowired

        @Bean
        public myBean createBean(){

             //construct bean
        }
   }
```

It's clear how these beans are running and what the class does, but I'm confused by two things, why it's needed, and rather it's even following the contract of @configuration.

All the definition I can find for @Configuration say that it is used to define beans with @Bean, I've not yet been able to find any other promise for the annotation.  Thus it seems like there would be no promise that the static class would even be constructed or recognized as a @Configuration file in it's own right? It clearly is, and I'm not surprised it would be, but does the @Configuration contract *guarantee* this behavior?

second, what is the advantage?  Presumably there are some reasons we need two classes, rather then removing the static class and putting all its annotations on the parent class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When bootstrapping nested classes, only someAutoConfiguration (in your example) need be registered against the application context. By virtue of being a nested `@Configuration` class, someConfiguration (in your example) will be registered automatically. This avoids the need to use an `@Import` annotation when the relationship between someAutoConfiguration & someConfiguration is already implicitly clear.

You will have to use `@Import(someConfiguration.class)` in case you chose otherwise.

Comment: Can you achieve the same thing with `@ComponentScan`?

Comment: looking back on an ancient question, neither answer was able to address why this code existed, which may just be because the code actually was pointless as my first instinct suggested.  You at least answered half of my question so picking this, someone deserves credit ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are confused between the two completely different things. A class annotated using `@Configuration` and containing Beans Definition provides an alternative to the XML based approach of Spring Context. There is no need of any nested class in this class.

If you are writing Integration Tests for your Application then you might use nested class in order to specify the Configuration. For example,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public Foo foobar() {
            return new Foo();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private Foo foobar;

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use your Configuration class (If you have defined any) as follows:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=YourConfiguration.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
```

Comment: I'm not the one doing this, the code I inherrited is.  I'm just trying to figure out why.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: that's what I was hoping someone could tell me :)  at this point my best impression is that there was some places where a static configuration class was used so calls could be made to it statically during configuration, and because everyone copy-pasted even those that didn't need the static class ended up doing it anyways.  Except the developers have been pretty good otherwise, I'm surprised they would be that sloppy, was wondering if I was missing something.